# Textarea doesn't break line on 'enter' press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a project with a lot of libraries, like `jQuery`, `Kendo` and `AngularJS`. After an update with many commits `textarea` stopped breaking to a new line by `[Enter]` press. Maybe, somewhere the event has been unbound or a library interrupts. I tried to get listeners for the object by `JQuery.data(element)`, but it got undefined. How can I debug it?

Comment: Try to reproduce a minimal snippet that reproduces the bug, for instance on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Adding to what @nicolallias recommended, be sure to add any relevant libraries into the snippet using CDNs in JSFiddle. That way it can closely replicate your own code.

Comment: In Chrome, press F12, go to *Sources* tab, at right side, look for *Event listener breakpoints*, then expand *Keyboard*. Happy debug.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the snippet, because there's a lot of code that generates the form from template and some others. Is keypress on this element some kinf of 'internal' event? Can it be interrupted or unbound somehow?

Comment: @c4off can you provide your code .? or you my try e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem. Somewhere in the code:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It was used to catch 'Enter' press, that led to another page, because menu element was focused on start.

Comment: yikes, maybe be a bit more specific than `document` there.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('textbox').keypress(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent any other binded event to be fired when user writes inside the textbox.

Answer (score 4):

In my case Enter and arrow keys were not working, key-press wasn't detecting the events, changed to key-down, it worked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input, textarea').keydown(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem and this one solved mine. thanks